# Finding the limit of recurrence sequence $x_{n+1}=\frac{3}{4} x_n + \frac{1}{4} x_{n-1}$

Tags: calculus, limits

> Find the limit of the following sequence: $x_1 = 1, x_2 = 6, x_{n+1} =
>  \frac{3}{4} x_n + \frac{1}{4} x_{n-1} $
>
> The answer is 5.

Here is what I tried:

$$\frac{3}{4} x_n + \frac{1}{4} x_{n-1} < x_n \Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{4} x_{n-1} < \frac{1}{4} x_n \Leftrightarrow x_{n-1} < x_n $$

Given into account that $x_1 < x_2$, the above derivation implies that any $x_n: n>2$ is less than 6. Also, it's obvious that each term of the sequence is positive, i.e. sequence is bounded.

I don't know what to do next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

So,  we have  $$4x_{n+1}-3x_n-x_{n-1}=0$$

Use [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving) to find  $$x_m=A(1)^m+B\left(-\frac14\right)^m$$ where $A,B$ are arbitrary finite constants

$$\lim_{m\to\infty}x_m=A$$

Now, use $x_1=1,x_2=6$ to find $A$

Comment: Thanks, it turns out I know this way of solving, but somehow I didn't recognize it in this problem. $y^{2}-\frac{3}{4}y-\frac{1}{4}\rightarrow1;-\frac{1}{4}\rightarrow y=A+B\left(-\frac{1}{4}\right)^{t}\rightarrow y=1+\frac{1}{4}B+B\left(-\frac{1}{4}\right)^{t}\rightarrow y=5+16\left(-\frac{1}{4}\right)^{t}\rightarrow\lim y=5$

Comment: @Yaldc, My pleasure. In fact, we don't need the exact value of finite $B$

Answer (score 4):

Hint: to find the limit show that $y_n=x_{n+1}-x_n$ is geometric series and recover $x_n$ from $y_n$ using the identity $x_n-x_1=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}y_k$.