# Limit of succession $a_1 = 0$, $a_2 = 1$, $a_{n + 2} = \frac{1}{3} a_{n + 1} + \frac{2}{3} a_n$

Tags: real-analysis

I want to find the limit of the following succession.

$a_1 = 0$, $a_2 = 1$, $a_{n + 2} = \frac{1}{3} a_{n + 1} + \frac{2}{3} a_n$

I know it converges because we have:

$$|a_{n+2} - a_{n+1}| = \left| \frac{1}{3} a_{n + 1} + \frac{2}{3} a_n - a_n \right| = \frac{1}{3} |a_{n +1} - a_n|$$

Which means it's Cauchy and that it converges.

In a recursion I usually take limits, but in this case I get $a = \frac{1}{3} a + \frac{2}{3} a$, so I get $a = a$ which provides no information.

Do I have to start in $a_n$ using the recursion till I get down to $a_1$ and $a_2$ and then compute the value? Or is there a quicker and less tedious way?

Comment: Similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/856888/42969. – Here: $a_{n+2}-a_{n+1} = -\frac 23 (a_{n+1}-a_n)$.

Comment: @MartinR is there a guide to searches to find answers like yours?

Comment: See [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265/42969), in particular [How to search with Approach0](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/29267/42969).